# Where do I take vehicles that Simeon has asked for?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I had a text message from Simeon requesting some cars. About 2 hours later I stole a car that happened to be one he wanted.

Problem is I had no idea where to take it. There was nothing on the map and no other instructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the bottom of the screen it should tell you that the car needs to be resprayed, so you have to go to Los Santos Customs and respray it (any color will do). After you've done that, an objective marker will show up on your map and gps, telling you where to go.

Comment: I think the problem is you get told to take it to LSC to repair it if it's damaged. After that, it says at the bottom to take it to LSC but doesn't say why so I couldn't figure out why I had to go there again.

Comment: Odd, I don't recall it ever being asked to repair it, because Simeon will accept the car even if it's nearly destroyed, as long as it's resprayed (he will deduct the repair costs from your reward)

Comment: Unless i've missed something LSC will /require/ you to repair the car before allowing a respray; so if you've damaged it before that point you'll need to do both.

Comment: Bottom? I don't see anything like this.